# I want to be able to customize buttons on the Camera screen for Banuba VE, is there such an option?

Tags: video, icons, editor, customization

I want to be able to customize the buttons on the Camera screen, adding our branded icons instead of the default ones that you have.
I would appreciate a guide on it.
Our main platform is iOS but info on Android would be useful too.